# Google Datastore not retrieving entities

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

I have been working with the google cloud library, and I can successfully save data in DataStore, specifically from my particle electron device (Used their tutorial here https://docs.particle.io/tutorials/integrations/google-cloud-platform/)

The problem I am now having is retrieving the data again.
I am using this code, but it is not returning anything

```
    function getData(){
var data = [];
const query = datastore.createQuery('ParticleEvent').order('created');
datastore.runQuery(query).then(results => {

    const event = results[0];
    console.log(results);

    event.forEach(data => data.push(data.data));
});

console.log(data)
```

}

But each time it is returning empty specifically returning this :
`[ [], { moreResults: 'NO_MORE_RESULTS', endCursor: 'CgA=' } ]`
, and I can't figure out why because I have multiple entities saved in this Datastore.

Thanks

Comment: You should add the code creating the entities. Assuming that I'm looking it the right one, there doesn't appear to be a `created` property in the `ParticleEvent` entities. Try the query without ordering (and/or maybe ordering by `published_at` instead?), if that provides results it's most likely the case.

Comment: Thanks that has fixed it, I was struggling to find appropriate documentation and assumed that the order worked like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [tutorial.js](https://github.com/particle-iot/google-cloud-datastore-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial.js) from the repo mentioned in the tutorial I see the `ParticleEvent` entities are created using this data:

```
var obj = {
    gc_pub_sub_id: message.id,
    device_id: message.attributes.device_id,
    event: message.attributes.event,
    data: message.data,
    published_at: message.attributes.published_at
}
```

This means the entities don't have a `created` property. I suspect that ordering the query by such property name is the reason for which the query doesn't return results. From [Datastore Queries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries) (emphasis mine):

> The results include all entities that **have at least one value for
>   every property named in the filters and sort orders**, and whose
>   property values meet all the specified filter criteria.

I'd try ordering the query by `published_at` instead, that appears to be the property with a meaning closest to `created`.